# Can't see Xcode after Installer says "Successfully Installed"

Tags: xcode, xcode4, osx-snow-leopard

I had the following version of Xcode on my MAC mimi -

```
Version: 4.2 (4C128)
Location: /Developer
Applications:
Xcode: 4.2 (821)
Instruments: 4.2 (4209)
Dashcode: 3.0.2 (335)
SDKs:
Mac OS X:
10.6: (4C128)
iPhone OS:
5.0: (9A5259f)
iPhone Simulator:
3.2: (7W367a)
4.0: (8A400)
4.1: (8B117)
4.2: (8C134)
4.3: (8H7)
5.0: (9A5259f)
```

Everything was fine. But i had to install 4.1 snow-leopard ver (Mac Mini is running MAC OS X 10.6.8) for some reason.

So, i removed the Xcode 4.2 ver using the following command -

```
sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all
```

And then installed the 4.1 version. The installer program said it's completed the installation successfully.

But, I am unable to find the Xcode.app either at the default /Developer/Applications or /Developer locations.

I did a complete search for Xcode.app on my hard drive starting from root location. Still no luck -

```
find / -name "Xcode.app"
```

Can someone tell me what im missing here pls?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Look for an app called "Install Xcode". Run *that* to install Xcode, if you find it and you think that is what was installed, in fact.

This new "meta install" appeared semi-recently, and I had to search around to find this "Install Xcode" app because I had the same experience: "Where's Xcode?!"

Comment: Great. I do see "Install Xcode" under the user Applications folder. Thanks a lot. I have started the installation and it looks like it's going to take some time to complete. Will report back. Have accepted your answer as well.

Comment: While, i m waiting for this to complete, i have another simple install-related question - The Install program gives me an option to "Choose Install location", but that only seems to give me an option on which DISKs to choose for installation - not essentially the destination folder on a chosen disk. For folks with only installed disk [the default MAC HD disk], this "Choose Install Location" is useless. I was wondering if selecting the destination folder was only an option with OSX Lion and not really available for snow leaporders. TIA.

Comment: No, you can select any folder you like, on any disk you have. I have, in some instances, had to create the folder in the Finder first, and then it was available to select as a destination in the installer. I regularly install in top-level directories like /Xcode4 (or whatever you like).

Comment: I see. I had to first create the folder :) Then it shows up. Installation completed and this time, i can see the Xcode. Launching it is causing internal error and crashing :( Well, i will play around that for a while before i seek help :) Thanks @MarkGranoff